# Query to get 4 elements for each Unique Country for Room

Tags: sqlite, android-room, android-livedata

Please refer to the table in the image attached. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGHfK.png   (From W3Schools)

What I am trying to achieve is to get at max 4 elements from each unique country

**Pseudo code:**

1) Find all distinct countries (Mexico, USA, Canada, etc)

2) get any 4 elements for each of those unique countries.

**Expected Outcome:**

4 random people for Mexico

4 random people for USA

1 random people for Canada (Total people from Canada in table = 1)

3 random people from India (Total people from India in table = 3)

The query for SQLite is

```
select * from(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY Country DESC) AS rn
from Customers) sub
where sub.rn < 5
```

But my question is how can i convert this for Room Query in Android. Is it even possible? 
I would just need the LiveData  from the query of the room. I can then parse the result to handle the data.

I am not really the database guy so I am struggling with this.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: The query you posted does not return **random** people from each country.

Answer (score 0):

In short you will have to use an alternative query that doesn't use Window Functions.

Support for Window functions and therefore the use of OVER was introduced in SQLite 3.25.0.

The highest supported version of SQLite in the official Android list is SQLite 3.19. As such OVER is invalid syntax and you cannot use Window functions. android.database.sqlite